# Uniform convergence of integral and derivatives of $f_n(x)=\frac{\sin nx}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

> Let $f_n$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ be: $$f_n(x)=\frac{\sin nx}{n}$$ Let $f$ be the pointwise limit of $f_n$
>
> Denote $F(x)=\int_{-\pi}^x f(y)dy$ and $F_n(x)=\int_{-\pi}^x f_n(y)dy$.
>
> On $[-\pi,\pi]$:
>
> a)Does $F_n \rightarrow F$ uniformly?
>
> b)Does $f'_n \rightarrow f'$ uniformly?

**My Solution:**

First I found the pointwise limit of $f_n(x)$ to be $f=0$. I then said that $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformply since $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup | \frac{ \sin (nx)}{n}-0|=0<\epsilon$$

Hence, I thought about interchanging the limit and integral signes, to show that both a and b are true. However, this is not necessarily true, e.g. my answer to b is false, **why can't I interchange?**

a)
$F_n(x)=\int_{-\pi}^x f_n(y)dy=\int_{-\pi}^x \frac{ \sin (nx)}{n}dy=-\cos (\pi x)/n^2+\cos (-\pi x)/n^2=0$ which agrees with the zero integral.

b)$\frac{ \sin (nx)}{n}'=\cos (nx)$ but $\sup |\cos (nx)-0|\ne 0$ hence it's false.

Comment: For Part (b), you  are correct.  The derivative of $f_n'(x)$ does not have a point-wise limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ |F_n(x)-0|=|\int_{-\pi}^x f_n(y)dy \ | \leq \int_{-\pi}^x |f_n(y)|\leq \int_{-\pi}^x \frac{1}{n}dy \leq 2\pi/n$$
We wee that independent of $x$, the limit goes to zero. Also note that $F=0$ as $f=0$ for all $x$.

Here you could interchange because convergence $F_n \rightarrow F$ is uniform. Derivatives do not converge even pointwise, take $x=\pi/2$ for instance. So, we don't expect anything, any relation between $f_n'$ and $f'$. Derivatives have zero respect for convergence (even uniform convergence), and it is plausible, take a vary rigid saw-shaped function, positive and bounded. Then multiply be $\frac {1}{n}$'s to have a uniformly converging seq about whose derivative you can say nothing!

Comment: What do you mean derivatives don't converge pointwise?  The statement $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ makes perfect sense.  And if for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N(\epsilon)$, such that for all $x\in A$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$ then $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on the set $A$.  However, in the case here, $f_n'(x)$ has no limit.

Comment: "$f′_n(x)$  has no limit, " That's what I meant!

Comment: Sorry! I meant (of course) in this example.